# Spread Limit vs Pot Limit

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy

Are there any advantages to a [spread limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker#Spread_limit) game over a [pot limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker#Pot_limit) game? The variable bet structure tend to throw several people's sense of betting seemingly to make it either a looser bet or everyone just bets the top of the spread.

Comment: What kind of advantages/disadvantages do you mean? Strategic? Organizational? Also, can you provide more details or a link on what a spread limit game is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find spread limit to work best in friendly games with weaker players, where they can make 1 or 2 buyins last all night.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part it is going to mirror, fixed limit.

Math will be more important, since you can't control pot odds as much, but you can always predict what calling someone down to the river will cost you.

Depends on the spread, but you can seriously use odds and proper mathematical play to your advantage vs pot limit very much like fixed limit.